# Cannot see sources will debugging on local JBoss server

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jboss

I have a project producing a `.war` file, I created a local `JBoss 7.1` server in `eclipse` referencing my local `JBoss` installation. Then I start the local server in debug mode, copy my war file to `{JBOSS_HOME}\standalone\deployments`, and it deploys it correctly.

But when I add a breakpoint in `eclipse`, the code stops like it should, but showing me a "`Source not found`" white page.

How can I link or synchronize the source code to my local server? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I solved my problem and it seems pretty obvious now that I found it :

My project is generating a `projectname.war`, and a `projectname-sources.jar`, I just had to deploy also the `projectname-sources.jar`...